# How to save the time in a variable apart from the system time?

Tags: c#, datetime

How can i save the time in `dd/mm/yyyy` (for UK) and `mm/dd/yyyy` (for US) formats in variables apart from the system time settings? I'm taking the data from a DateTimePicker control. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Create a dictionary for specific culture key and save date in it...

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to save them to a string, you can use the [DateTime.ToString(string format)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) function .

For a list of format strings, you can check out the MSDN articles on [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) and [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

You can get the DateTime selected by your DateTimePicker by accessing the [DateTimePicker.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) property.

For your examples, the following should suffice:

```
DateTimePicker myDateTimePicker = new DateTimePicker();

// ... other code ...

DateTime dtm = myDateTimePicker.Value;
string dateUK = dtm.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"); // dd/mm/yyyy (UK)
string dateUS = dtm.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"); // mm/dd/yyyy (US)
```

**Update:** I updated the code to include retrieving the DateTime from a DateTimePicker, rather than an arbitrary DateTime variable.

Comment: If you want to take this to the next step...  Make a wrapper class and add properties `USFormat` and `UKFormat`.  You may be able to `implement` the `DateTime` class with your own and add the properties.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little vague...

Use DateTime.Parse if you're concerned about format or use DateTime.ToUniversalTime to save the UTC equivalent of the input time.

Comment: If you expand your question with a real world example, I think I or others could provide more accurate answers.

Comment: I am using a DateTimePicker to select a date. It can be today or any other date. I wanna save that date taken from that DateTimePicker to in 2 of the formats i have stated above. That's what i want. I wanna save the same date taken from the DateTimePicker control in both formats in 2 string variables.

Comment: In that case, Jon Senchna's answer is bang on, just replace the first line with the output of your date-time picker.

Comment: The DateTimePicker control has a Value property, use .Format on that property (as it returns a DateTime).

Comment: @aroshlakshan I updated my response above to show using the value from a DateTimePicker.  You should be able to just take the last 3 lines (and replace `myDateTimePicker` with the name of your DatetimePicker instance).